# How do I search files in a folder to be moved to another folder in a certain condition in Python 3?

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

I will try to explain a little more clearly: I am trying to figure out how to use shutil and os modules on Python 3.8.5 to be able to take a look at a folder, determine if its contents have been created and/or modified within the last 24 hours... and then if they have, move those files to another folder.

I am going to try to link up the code I have here, I'm still pretty new at using Stackoverflow, so I apologize:

```
import shutil
import os

shutil.copystat(' \Users\aaron\Desktop\checkFiles\File B.txt', "\Users\aaron\Desktop\needToCopy\"," follow_symlinks=True)
```

This code keeps giving me invalid syntax errors. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have even looked at docs.python.org, but, since I am very new to coding, it was pretty greek to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what are you trying to achieve by using `shutil.copystat`. It only copies the stats and permissions onto the path. (If your `File B.txt` is read only, the `needToCopy` will be also read only)

In order to find out creation and modification times, consult [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501288/1253121).

I would approach the check for 24 hour time window modification like this:

```
import os, time
DIR_PATH = "."
for filename in os.listdir(DIR_PATH):
    if os.path.getmtime(filename) >= (time.time() - 60*60*24): print(filename)
```

And for the moving part, there is (for example) `shutil.move`. So it could look like this:

```
import os, time, shutil
SRC_PATH = "."
TARGET_PATH = "../"
for filename in os.listdir(SRC_PATH):
    if os.path.getmtime(filename) >= (time.time() - 60*60*24): 
        shutil.move(os.path.join(SRC_PATH, filename), TARGET_PATH)
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me with this issue, it solved everything wonderfully. I really appreciate this.